# Android: unable to find explicit activity class?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, manifest

Within my application I am getting the following error from logcat, What is the error with my code? I have searched for over an hour online and cannot solve the issue.

It is relating to the **intent** that I am trying to use in order to open up a new activity but I am not sure how to solve it.

```
   07-20 20:02:18.976: E/AndroidRuntime(7381): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-9022
07-20 20:02:18.976: E/AndroidRuntime(7381): Process: com.example.brianapp, PID: 7381
07-20 20:02:18.976: E/AndroidRuntime(7381): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.brianapp.MeditationResults }
07-20 20:02:18.976: E/AndroidRuntime(7381):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1672)
07-20 20:02:18.976: E/AndroidRuntime(7381):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1442)
07-20 20:02:18.976: E/AndroidRuntime(7381):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3511)
07-20 20:02:18.976: E/AndroidRuntime(7381):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3472)
07-20 20:02:18.976: E/AndroidRuntime(7381):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3714)
07-20 20:02:18.976: E/AndroidRuntime(7381):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3682)
07-20 20:02:18.976: E/AndroidRuntime(7381):     at com.example.brianapp.Meditation$2.run(Meditation.java:115)
```

It is relating from **this code section** as this error only occured once I changed this code section:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.meditation);

        //new thread
                Thread timer = new Thread() {

                    /**
                     * Method that firstly starts the thread and makes it sleep,
                     * then using intents opens the main activity using
                     * a reference to its name
                     */
                    public void run() {

                        try {
                            //sleep for 3.5 seconds
                            sleep(15000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // exceptions caught here
                            e.printStackTrace(); 

                        } finally {

                        Intent openActivity = new Intent("com.example.brianapp.MeditationResults");
//                          //Start activity
                        startActivity(openActivity);


                        }
                    }

                };
                //Start timer
                timer.start();
```

The following is my **manifest**, note that I have included an intent filter for this class (meditation), the class I am trying to open with the intent is called MeditationResults:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.brianapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.brianapp.Menu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.brianapp.menu" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.brianapp.Meditation"
            android:label="Meditation" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.brianapp.meditation" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.brianapp.MeditationResults"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_meditation_results" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.brianapp.UserName"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_user_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.brianapp.ServerInterface"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_server_interface" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this in your manifest to

```
   <activity
            android:name="com.example.brianapp.MeditationResults"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_meditation_results" >
   </activity>
```

to

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.brianapp.MeditationResults"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_meditation_results" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.brianapp.MeditationResults" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this has solved the problem (and saved me a sleepless night lol)